# LogicApp Same Name Values from different Nodes into single array of values

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I have a parse JSON step which outputs this sort of structure

```
[
  {
    "Value": "Sample Value 1"
  },
  {
    "Value": "Sample Value 2"
  }
]
```

I would like to transform the following structure

```
[
"Sample Value 1",
"Sample Value 2"
]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the original array and the value of add each `value` property to a linear string based array.

This flows shows you the basic steps ...

[image: Flow]

**Firstly**, I created a new variable of type `Array` that stored your original data.

**Next**, I initialised another variable that will hold the results of the output.  When initialised, it was with no value.

**Finally**, using a `For each` action, I loop over the original array and within that, there's an `Append to array variable` step which adds in the value of the `value` property for each item to the `Simple Array` variable.  The expression in the `*Value` field is ...

```
item()?['value']
```

... that will retrieve the value for each item and append it accordingly.

This is the end result ...

[image: Result]

One thing to note is, if you want the simple array to be in the same order as the original array values, you need to go to the settings on the `For each` step and turn concurrency on to equals `1`.

[image: Concurrency]

Comment: Hey, many thanks. Just tried it. That works really well. Appreciate your help. Cheers.